# How to convert data into timeseries for column groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data with timestamps. Users do tasks, and the timestamp is recorded. Each user is identified by a 'uid'. I want to convert this data into 10-minute granular time series, but for each user separately. So, timestamp goes in chronological order for uid=1 separately, then for uid=2 and so on.

From:

```
timestamp          uid    var
2020-01-01 10:00    1     10
2020-01-01 10:04    2     20 
2020-01-01 20:02    2     15
2020-01-01 21:20    1     10
.. 
2020-01-15 23:12    1     5
```

To:

```
timestamp           uid   var
2020-01-01 10:00     1    10
2020-01-01 10:10     1    NaN
2020-01-01 10:20     1    NaN
...
2020-01-15 23:10     1    5
2020-01-01 10:00     2    20
2020-01-01 10:10     2    NaN
2020-01-01 10:20     2    NaN
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grouped by `uid` column and `resample` 10T

```
import numpy as np

(df.groupby('uid')
 .resample(rule='10T')['var'].sum()
 .reset_index(level=0)
 .replace({0: np.NaN}))
```

Comment: thanks! do you have any idea how I can forward fill the missing values for 1 hour (6 rows) after each 'var' column entry?

Comment: need example for answer

Comment: I updated my post to give you an explanation.

Comment: i don know why are you asking additional question without `Accepted` when  question has been resolved. use `asfreq` with `method='ffill'`